# Was there a better way to modify this string other than what I did?

Tags: c#, regex, string, path

I have strings like this:

> Sprites\/tilesTest.png

I wanted to swap **\/** with **/**, and remove extensions, so it would look like this

> Sprites/tilesTest

This is what I did:

```
string GetImageToLoadPath(string path)
{
    path = path.Replace("\\/", "/");
    path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("."));
    return path;
}
```

Was there any better way to do it? Is there any way to do it using regex?

Comment: if this way works for you then what problem are you trying to address? Is it performance? Inaccuracy? Or are you just looking to expand your knowledge by seeing how this would be done using Regex? If so what do you have so far on the RegEx side?

Comment: No, this is the easiest way to do what you need. Please also remember that regular expression are not the Holy grail

Comment: @Peter4499 Just expand knowledge. I'm a complete noob in regex, I just looked at this problem, and though to myself "hmm that might be a thing people do with regex", then I went on doing some regex tutorials, but it seemed like regex is more aimed to when you have a list of strings, and you want to filter them. But I still wanted to ask to be sure.

Comment: @FelipeMüller I would've been clearer in my question. To be clear, they way you're doing it now is faster then regex. In my experience the more complex the search patters across larger text is usually where RegEx becomes the better way to go, still not as good as string manipulation but cleaner and faster to code. I'll see if I can post a RegEx answer to your challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt a regex is the proper tool for handling filepaths like this.

When it comes to directories and file names, `Path.Combine` (together with `Path.GetDirectoryName` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`) might be handy, especially when the directory separator is not known. As for the `\/` replacement, the way you did seems the best.

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s))
    .Replace(@"\/", "/");
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/tI96lF):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = @"Sprites\/tilesTest.png";
        Console.Write(GetStr(s));
    }
    public static string GetStr(string s) {
        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(s), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)).Replace(@"\/", "/");
    }
}
```

So, `Path.GetDirectoryName` gets the folder path, `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` gets the file name up to but excluding the extension, and `Path.Combine` joins the path with the name with the system default directory separator symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a regular expression at all for this. String functions are really helpful to solve this kind of problem and I would do the same what you already have done but probably make it one liner saying

```
string GetImageToLoadPath(string path)
{
    return path.Replace("\\/", "/").Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, you can get more details from : [Regex.Replace Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string input = @"Sprites\/tilesTest.png";
            string pattern = @"(\\)?(.png)?";
            string replacement = "";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

            Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
            Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```